# How to select dropdown value from div list in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In the HTML below, there is a `div` tab that contains an `li` list which appears as a drop down. I want to select a value from this list using an `xpath` locator.

**Html code.**

```
<div id="boundlist-1277-listWrap" data-ref="listWrap" role="presentation" class="x-boundlist-list-ct x-unselectable x-no-touch-scroll x-scroll-container" style="overflow: auto; height: 298px;">
  <ul id="boundlist-1277-listEl" data-ref="listEl" class="x-list-plain x-scroll-scroller">
    <li role="option" unselectable="on" class="x-boundlist-item x-boundlist-item-over" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="0" data-recordid="20478" data-boundview="boundlist-1277">Assessment Completion - Returned To Functional Validation</li>
    <li role="option" unselectable="on" class="x-boundlist-item" tabindex="-1" data-recordindex="1" data-recordid="20479" data-boundview="boundlist-1277">Assessment Completion - Workflow Ended</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

**Explanation:** Use `Relative xpath` method, your dropdown selection value is inside the `Ul` tag. so start your `xpath` with `ul` tag and then move ahead with `li` tag along with `text` method.

Click on this **Assessment Completion - Workflow Ended**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[contains(text(), 'Assessment Completion - Workflow Ended')]")).click();
```

> OR

Click on this **Assessment Completion - Returned To Functional Validation**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[contains(text(), 'Assessment Completion - Returned To Functional Validation')]")).click();
```